# How can I modify the url on a http redirect?

Tags: node.js

On a statuscode=302, where is the url that the application is redirected to ? Is it in the field uri of the response headers section ? An how can I modify it on the fly ?

```
case 'post':
      r = request.post({
        url: newurl,
        form: req.body,
        headers: req.headers,
      }, function callback(err, HttpResponse, body) {
         debug(res.statusCode);      /* 302  */
      });
```

Here is the response from the above POST request:

```
{ response:
   { headers:
      { 'content-type': 'text/html',
        'content-length': '332',
        location: 'https://11.21.164.11:10635/html/listing.tml?showError=&showMessage=Created%20successfully.',
        uri: 'https://11.21.164.11:10635/html/listing.tml?showError=&showMessage=Created%20successfully.' },
     statusCode: 302,
     body: '\r\n <html><head>\r\n<title>Found</title>\r\n </head></html>\r\n'} }
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP response with 302 status code will additionally provide a URL in the location header field. The user agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field.

--from:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: Is the location field URL modifiable on the fly once I detect the 302 status code ?